# jQuery click display elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Tell me please why the element is not deleted and not displayed by turns?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 

    <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="main">
    <img id="left_btn" src="images/left_btn.png" allt="left" />
    <img id="right_btn" src="images/right_btn.png" allt="right" />

    <div class="pic_box">
        <div  class="gall_one">
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum1</h2>
            <img  src="images/mlp1.png" allt="mlp" />
            <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
        </div>
        <div  class="gall_one2">
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum2</h2>
            <img  src="images/mlp2.png" allt="mlp" />
            <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
        </div>
        <div  class="gall_one3">
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum3</h2>
            <img  src="images/mlp3.jpg" allt="mlp" />
            <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/my_scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script:

```
c$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".pic_box  > div").hide();
    $(".pic_box  > div:first").show();
    $("#right_btn").click(function(){

    for(var img1=0; img1<3; img1++){
        gall();
    }
    function gall(){
        $(".pic_box > div").show().prev("div").remove();
    }   
});
```

I want to do when you click on `#right_btn` removed one div and displays the following.

Comment: What is this attribute `allt`?

Comment: When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  Is the click handler invoked at all?  When you step through the code, do your selectors find the elements you expect them to find?  Be specific.

Comment: You have a for loop, that will remove all of them right away...

Comment: The whole thing doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a way to go to the next div in a sequence of divs.

Here's a link to a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/0uop9rzL/7/

In your current approach, you are using a `for-loop` in which you have hard coded the number of divs that you're cycling through. Even if the logic in your `gall` function actually did show the next box, what if you want to add additional divs in the future? More importantly, why would you need to cycle through all of the divs *each time* you click the `next` button?

In my example I added a `data-next` attribute to the currently visible box (taking advantage of [JQuery's data function](http://api.jquery.com/data/)). I am able to find the currently visible box by using the `:visible` selector (i.e. `mainBox.find("div:visible");`.

There are many approaches to this problem, but you may want to familiarize yourself with some of the tools that I've shown you and more of JQuery's abilities by visiting http://api.jquery.com/

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <button id="left_btn" >&lt;- </button>
    <button id="right_btn">-&gt;</button>
    <div id="pic_box">
        <div id="gall_one" data-next="#gall_one2">
             <h2>Lorem Ipsum1</h2>

            <img src="images/mlp1.png" allt="mlp" />
            <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
        </div>
        <div id="gall_one2" data-next="#gall_one3">
             <h2>Lorem Ipsum2</h2>

            <img src="images/mlp2.png" allt="mlp" />
            <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
        </div>
        <div id="gall_one3" data-next="#gall_one">
             <h2>Lorem Ipsum3</h2>

            <img src="images/mlp3.jpg" allt="mlp" />
            <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pic_box  > div").hide();
    $("#pic_box  > div:first").show();
    $("#right_btn").click(function () {
        var mainBox = $("#pic_box");
        var activeBox = mainBox.find("div:visible");
        var nextBox = mainBox.find(activeBox.data("next"));
        activeBox.hide();
        nextBox.show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of ways to do it. One way is to just added hidden classes

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".btn").on("click", function() {  //click on button

    var nextPrev = $(this).data("dir");  //determine if we are going back or forward

    var active = $(".pic_box > div:visible")  //get the current visible element
        .addClass("hidden");  //hide it
        var next;
        if (nextPrev==="prev") {
            next = active.prev();  //get previous div
            if(next.length===0) next = $(".pic_box > div:last");  //if there is no prev, select the last one
        } else {
            next = active.next();  //get next div
            if(next.length===0) next = $(".pic_box > div:first"); //if there is no next div, select the first one      
        }
        next.removeClass("hidden");  //take off the hidden class
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <button class="btn" data-dir="prev"><img id="left_btn" src="images/left_btn.png" alt="left" /></button>
    <button  class="btn" data-dir="next" ><img id="right_btn"src="images/right_btn.png" alt="right" /></button>

<div class="pic_box">
    <div  class="gall_one">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum1</h2>
        <img  src="images/mlp1.png" allt="mlp" />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
    </div>
    <div  class="gall_one2 hidden">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum2</h2>
        <img  src="images/mlp2.png" allt="mlp" />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
    </div>
    <div  class="gall_one3 hidden">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum3</h2>
        <img  src="images/mlp3.jpg" allt="mlp" />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden { display:none }
```

**Fiddle**

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nzhyko9s/)